# Can SQL tell me how many row(s) were updated?

Tags: php, mysql

I would use only a single query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE gallery SET order = (order+1) WHERE id_categ = ".$id;
$res = mysql_query($sql);

...
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

> mysql_affected_rows — Get number of
>   affected rows in previous MySQL
>   operation

**Example:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE gallery SET order = (order+1) WHERE id_categ = ".$id;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
printf("Affected rows: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

***Note*** that the `mysql_affected_rows()` return you the affected rows whether updated/deleted of your ***last*** run query. For example:

```
$sql = "UPDATE gallery SET order = (order+1) WHERE id_categ = ".$id;
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE gallery2 SET order = (order+1) WHERE id_categ = ".$id;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Now if you do:

```
printf("Affected rows: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

It will return the affected rows for the *last* query that is `gallery2` table's query.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) should to the job.

Copied from the manual:

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET used=1 WHERE id < 10");
printf ("Updated records: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
// Prints: "Updated Records: 10"
```

Comment: Guess it'll be 9, because the first id will be 1, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at something like

- [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)
- [PHP mysql_affected_rows()
  Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_affected_rows.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use

> [mysql_affected_rows()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

after your query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE gallery SET order = (order+1) WHERE id_categ = ".$id;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$rowsAffected = mysql_affected_rows();
```

Edit: Damn, you guys are fast ;)